# How can I expand wildcards in Spring properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-io

I am developing spring boot application and I want to inject Collections of resources like this:

```
@Value("${app.users-location}")
Collection<Resource> csvResources;
```

inside `application.properties` I wrote following:

```
app.users-location=/feed/*.csv
```

But it doesn't work as expected:

[image: /src/main/resources containing a feed folder with 5 CSVs]

For that situation I expect to see Collection of 5 elements of type `Resource`.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: What's the image supposed to show? My network blocks imgur.

Comment: Also, Spring does not and cannot expand wildcards. You will have to autowire a string and do the wildcard expansion yourself.

Comment: @Michael It shows that src/main/resources folder has the 'feed' folder and that folder contains 5 csv files

Comment: @Michael, I understand that I can do everything by hands but I prefer to let spring work instead of me)

Comment: In which case, even if Spring could expand the wildcards, it would not be correct. `/feed/*.csv` is absolute, and you are trying to use a relative path.

Comment: Me too. But Spring cannot do everything. And this is something it can't do.

Comment: You need to use table of Resource. It will works only with `Resource[]`

Comment: @Michael,please tale a look  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57390577/2674303 solution with array was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person with nick `m.antkowicz` - https://stackoverflow.com/users/4153426/m-antkowicz

provided correct answer but then removed it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57373605/2674303

His solution was to use Array instead of list:

```
@Value("${app.users-location}")
Resource[] resources;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println(resources);
}
```

I checked it and it really works!!!

Comment: @m.antkowicz, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

That is valid :

```
@Value("app.users-location")
String foo; // inject "/feed/*.csv"
```

And that is also valid ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards)) :

```
@Value("classpath*:/feed/*.csv")
Collection<Resource> resources; // inject all resources located in this classpath
```

But I don't know how to mix them in a single annotation : that is resolve the property and use it with a `classpath*:` prefix. Maybe that is possible...

Whatever, as alternative I would inject this property `app.users-location=/feed/*.csv`and I would use `@PostConstruct` to get resources from that :

```
import org.springframework.core.io.support.*

@Value("${app.users-location}")
private String usersLocation;
private Collection<Resource> csvResources;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();   
    csvResources = 
    Arrays.asList(patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:/" + usersLocation));
}
```

Comment: it is a bit strange)

Comment: Not the time/possibility to test it right now but interesting. If if works and that it simpler with other solution, don't hesitate to accept  that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is discussion regarding your question:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12993

Seems current version doesn't support it